# multiprocessing: executing new function on a separate thread every n iterations of processes on other threads

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

**Context**

I have workers setup and running on a multi-threaded process running as follows:

```
global_iteration = mp.Value('i', 0)

workers = [Worker(global_iteration) for _ in range(num_threads)]

for w in workers:
    w.daemon=True
    w.start()

[w.join() for w in workers]
```

Each worker will perform some operation and then increment the global_iteration. For clarity, the worker class is defined as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Worker(mp.Process):
    def __init__(global_iteration):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.global_iteration = global_iteration

    def update_global_iteration():
        with self.global_iteration.get_lock():
            self.global_iteration+=1

    def run():
        ### Do something here ###
        self.update_global_iteration()
```

**My question:**

I want to run a function on a separate thread every n global_iterations. How can I do this?

For simplicity the function could be something like:

```
def print_global_iterations(global_iterations):
    print('Workers are currently on global iteration {}'.format(global_iterations))
```

Comment: Are you using multiprocessing and multithreading interchangeably? They are two different concepts with different uses, especially in python. Also, in your worker class constructor, is there a reason you haven't called the parent constructor? Seems like your worker class does not really need to subclass the multiprocessing.Process class

Comment: @Charchit - good spot. I actually have a complex code base and was simplifying the code  to maintain clarity on this forum. I do indeed call the parent in my actual code. Amended my code above.

Comment: In method `run` you have statement  `self.update_global_iteration`. That should be `self.update_global_iteration()`, right? There is really never necessary to subclass `multiprocessing.Process` since its initializer allows you to specify a *target*. This would make your `Worker` class potentially reusable in other contexts.

Comment: Not sure what the real issue is here. Presumably you know how to start a thread, so it's not that. So maybe it is how that thread can know when enough iterations have happened? If so, I guess it can either poll the variable regularly with sleeps  in between or you'll need to change your code such that when it updates the global variable it sends a message to the monitoring thread. Or maybe the question is something else?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, the issue is there are mulitple workers running each can update the global variable. your proposed solution can work i.e. when updating the global variable a message should be sent to the monitor thread. To make things concrete, would you be able to write out the code as a possible solution? Thanks!